# extjs 4 dynamic radio group with xtype in sencha architect

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

How can I create a component in sencha architect (or outside from architect), what has a custom xtype (user alias), and can be placed in a formpanel in architect.

The method is when the containing formpanel is created whith the given xtype then the component makes a ajax query, which gives back the radio buttons names, and configs, and the component show the correct buttons/names on the form panel.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

firstly you when you Ext.define() to extend a class you can specify an 'alias' in all lowercase using the format:

```
alias: 'widget.myxtype'
```

can you provide more detail regarding what you need to load into your form.

It sounds like you are looking to define a radiobuttongroup and have items dynamically loaded?

if so you could just load the form and have a fake form item (an array of 'radio button configs) that you load. Then you would extend the radio button group class insert items using .add() as child items as you would any other class

Comment: Yes I wan't radiobuttons which items loaded dynamically, and when thay are loaded I want to call the form.load method to load the form values. 

How can I extend the "radiobuttongroup" class in architect?

Comment: So I mean, If I written a component which has an xtype, how can I load it into architect and place it on a panel? (Which can be a dynamic thing.)

The other connecting question is, if i developed a login screen in one project how can I use the same in a new architect project as a ready component?